# How to dynamically group the rows based on N threshold?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, match-recognize

I want to know if there is a way we can do the below task in SQL. Can we do this with match_ recognize?

| Region | Role | employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | Analyst | 2 |
| Africa | S. Analyst | 3 |
| Africa | Manager | 9 |
| India | Partner | 2 |
| India | S. Manager | 7 |
| India | S. Analyst | 10 |
| USA | Analyst | 1 |
| USA | S. Analyst | 2 |
| USA | Partner | 2 |

Above is the input table. I want to group the role for a specific region where No. of employees is less than 6. So, In Africa, we have to combine Analyst, S.Analyst and manager (2+3+9) to overcome the threshold value of 6. Partner and S. Manager must be combined in India (2+7). S. Analyst can be left as it is. We have to drop the USA or add some flag that we can identify using a where clause. So the output should look like below.

**O/P**

| Region | Role | employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | Analyst_S. Analyst_Manager | 14 |
| India | Partner_S. Manager | 9 |
| India | S. Analyst | 10 |

Comment: @ Abra Thank you for your response!! If you filter out records where emp_count is less than 6 then Managers of Africa will get excluded. Then we are left with Analyst(2) and Senior Analyst(3) which aggregates to 5 < threshold value(which is 6 here). Moreover, how will you combine the roles, If you take a closer look at the O/P all roles are combined for Africa(Analyst_S.Analyst_Manager).

Comment: Oh, Thank you for your suggestion. Do you think we can solve this using match_recognize?

Comment: Sql server doesn't have match_recognize

Comment: Thank you for your response @siggemannen any other methods you know here will be helpful?

Comment: @RandomGuy I just tried a bit but couldn't succeed you could develop from here - https://dbfiddle.uk/YPgIauh6

Comment: How do you decide the order? The Africa Manager count 9 is greater than 6, and could be an own group.

Comment: @jarlh You are right about manager count but Analyst count(2) together with S. Analyst count(3) will not fulfill the threshold value. So clubbing it with manager. Had it been the alone group in Africa we could have shown it without combining with any oter group